# Function should wait for previous function to finish processing before executing next line of code

Tags: angular, typescript, wait

I am working on TypeScript and I am trying to call a Modal within a function. But a service is called which validates some stuff from the server and based on what is returned I want to call the modal or skip it altogether. In my case the server call is asynchronous which causes the modal to open even before we receive the response from the server. Is there any way to wait for the server response and then check the return code and open the modal accordingly?

As shown below: The `CheckandOpenModal` function should wait for `saveRecord` to finish and based on output value set, it should open the modal. But since the call is returned back to calling function before server response, output remains set to 0 and calls the modal.

How to resolve this?

Here is the primary function:

```
public output:number = 0;
CheckandOpenModal() {
  /* do something */
  this.saveRecord(); //Should wait for this to finish and return output
  if (this.output == 0) {
    //Call the modal window
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(editTableColComponent, {
      centered: true,
      scrollable: true
    });
  } else {
    //Do something
  }
}

saveRecord() {
    this.serv.checkTableRecord(this.objTableFields.tableNm, this.objTableFields.tableID).subscribe(data => {
      if (data.check.result == 1) {
        this.output = 1;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this question with angular, then I guess you are using obserables for async code.
Good thing is that with observables it's pretty easy to chain async operations!

```
import { map, Observable, tap } from "rxjs";

  checkAndOpenModal(): void {
    this.saveRecord()
      .pipe(
        tap((output) => {
          if (output == 0) {
            const modalRef = this.modalService.open(editTableColComponent, {
              centered: true,
              scrollable: true,
            });
          } else {
            //Do something
          }
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  saveRecord(): Observable<0 | 1> {
    return this.serv
      .checkTableRecord(this.objTableFields.tableNm, this.objTableFields.tableID)
      .pipe(map((data) => (data.check.result == 1 ? 1 : 0)));
  }
```

You can also return an observable to continue to chain it elsewhere. But remember to subscribe at the end of the chain, otherwhise no operation will be executed.

```
checkAndOpenModal(): Observable<1|0> {
  return this.saveRecord()
    .pipe(
      tap((output) => {
        if (output == 0) {
          const modalRef = this.modalService.open(editTableColComponent, {
            centered: true,
            scrollable: true,
          });
        } else {
          //Do something
        }
      })
    );
}
```

Glossary of used operators:

- **pipe**: to be able to chain operators on an observable
- **map**: to transform data emitted by the observable
- **tap**: to execute something in parallel when something is emitted in the observable

Some documentation:

- A good documentation for rxjs, observables and operators: https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview
- A tool to help you to find the operators that you need: https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree